# Javascript Decryption during Download

Tags: javascript, encryption, proxy, download

I'm building an ASPX website that should allow the user to download a CSV/Excel file (including the 'Save To' dialog). The CSV contains encrypted data - the decryption key is available at user side and should be kept secret against the webservice.
So decryption actually should be performed within the browser, a javascript implementation (sjcl) has proofed to work fine.
But how can the incoming datastream during a file download be influenced? Something like a browser hosted proxy performing the javascript decryption?

@closure: thanks a lot! Ajax is no problem, and the idea

```
<a href='data:application/csv;base64,aGVsbG87d29ybGQNCg=='>click</a>
```

is really cool, but it has two problems: it seems not work with IE and it is not the right approach for really huge tables. The solution should be able to handle many thousands of records, therefore we need some sort of download stream encoder/decrypter.

Comment: What do you mean by "influenced"?

Comment: Please excuse my bad english. With 'influenced' I meant to replace encrypted content by plain text.

Comment: That wouldn't work in any browser. Build the string in a script file or tag and set the anchor tag's href attribute with it.

Comment: I have fixed the data URI above to work as a standalone example. But it is useable for small data volumes only.

Answer (score 5):

Here are the steps to achieve this:

1. Instead of downloading the CSV directly to the client machine, fetch it via ajax
2. Once the data is received in via Ajax, parse the CSV via many available functions on internet. Let me know, if you need help on this. This function will convert the CSV to native Javascript Arrays.
3. Walk through the Array and covert the encrypted data to unencrypted data. Do it natively in the same Array.
4. Convert the array to CSV (Again there are functions in public domain)
5. Make a link (a element) and set the href to local data like `data:text/csv;charset=utf-8, + encodeURIComponent(csv)`
6. Present this link to the user and ask him to click on it to save the file locally.

Comment: This was an issue I have had for a while and this works perfectly I never thought of setting a link to local data before. So thank you for the tip